# How to create a numpy array of zeros of a list's length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list, say

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And i want to create a numpy array of zeros of that list's length.

If I do

```
b = np.zeros((len(a), 1))
```

I get

> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

instead of

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

**What is the best way to get the latter option?**

Comment: assuming it always returns data in this shape, you can just do `b = np.zeros((len(a), 1))[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have to care about shapes, use [`np.zeros_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html):

```
np.zeros_like(a)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

---

There's also the option of querying `np.shape`:

```
np.zeros(np.shape(a))
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Both options should work for ND lists as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't want to care about shapes"? Why are the options different?

Comment: @Gulzar from your code, it seems like your grief was mostly because you could not initialise `np.zeros` with the correct shape. So my first option was to give you something that did not need explicit dealing with the shape at all—let numpy handle that.

Answer (score 4):

You passed two-element `tuple` to `zeros`, so it produced 2D array, you can simply pass integer to `zeros`

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = np.zeros(len(a))
print(b) #prints [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
np.zeros(len(a), dtype=np.int)
```

It will return

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```